# is it possible to automatic run protractor E2E testcase by scheduling time interval

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have written some E2E testcases using protractor, selenium-server and angularjs, now I want to run the same testcases(with or without any change) again and again by setting some time interval for running, is there any way to do this,

I have seen jasmine and grunt, but I think they will work if found any change in file, but I have required to run all testcases after some interval(still if there is no change in file)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: U might be looking something like jenkins for scheduling. Right?

Comment: yes, is it possible with jenkins?

Comment: Yup ...u can schedule your jobs as per your need on jenkins.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, I have achieve my requirement, I have follow this link  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511

Comment: Now is it possible that i can get result of testcases after their execution(in any form either this save somewhere or mail to me)

Comment: If u setup jenkins, everything from build to the outputs will be saved according to the location u have configured. For mailing purpose u can use various plugins provided by Jenkins itself or if using maven, u can use maven-postman-plugin.